# Trying to set a QDeclarativeScriptString in a unit test (QTestLib)

Tags: qt, unit-testing, benchmarking, qml, qtestlib

I'm trying to create a benchmark for part of my [2D game framework](https://github.com/INdT/Quasi-Engine) (It's a QML extension) and I'm having problems to set a declarative script property of a QOBject.

The property declaration:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QDeclarativeScriptString script READ script WRITE setScript NOTIFY scriptChanged)
```

And one of my attempts to change the script is something like this:

```
ScriptBehavior *behavior = new ScriptBehavior(entity);
QDeclarativeProperty(behavior, "script").write("console.log(1);");
```

But it doesn't work (Run the benchmark, but don't write anything to te console).

I've tried to use setProperty and manually create a QDeclarativeScriptString and set the property, but nothing works.

When I try to create the QDeclarativeScriptString, It fails:

The code:

```
ScriptBehavior *behavior = new ScriptBehavior(entity);
QDeclarativeScriptString scriptString;
scriptString.setScript("console.log(1)");
behavior->setScript(scriptString);
```

The output:

```
QFATAL : UpdateBenchmark::behavior() Received signal 11
FAIL!  : UpdateBenchmark::behavior() Received a fatal error.
   Loc: [Unknown file(0)]
```

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: How are you evaluating the QDeclarativeScriptString?  Presumably via QDeclarativeExpression, in which case you'll need a context and scriptObject also.

Comment: Yup, I create a QDeclarativeExpression when setting the script: 

m_expression = new QDeclarativeExpression(m_script.context(), m_script.scopeObject(), m_script.script());

and then just call evaluate() when needed.